# Spring cloud config along with local property file, which will be preferred by an application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have application name with profile name property file, same is there on cloud config, my application is able to fetch property from cloud but somehow local property values are getting used in application i.e. local property file is over riding cloud config.

Is this correct?

I want to have my application to use cloud config property values than local one

Comment: can you provide the configuration files please.